# Failed to resolve : androidx

Tags: android, gradle, android-room

I was working with one of the codelabs tutorials https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3 .
Int which while editing buil.gradle (app) . I got **Failed to resolve : androidx** ,**Failed to resolve : androidx.arch** & **Failed to resolve : com.google.android**

*build.gradle*

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidroomcodelabs"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.2.2.4"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.2.2.4"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.2.2.4"

// Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.2.3.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.2.3.0"

// UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.1.0.0"

// Testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.1.2.0"

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake that I made by not seeing the difference in **build.gradle(app)** and **build.gradle**. If in case someone ran into same error follow this.It will take me two days to accept my answer but it worked for me.

`build.gradle(app)`

```
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
   implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

// UI
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

// Testing
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"
```

Leaving the roomVersion, archLifecycleVersion, coreTestingVersion & materialVersion as they are and adding the below version in **build.gradle**

`build.gradle`

````
    roomVersion = '2.2.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    materialVersion = '1.0.0'
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you are missing the reference to the Google's maven repository in the project level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // this allow to lookup in the Google's maven repository
        jcenter()
    }

    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // this allow to lookup in the Google's maven repository
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Thank you for your contribution Wang.