# gradle can not resolve room version 2.3.0

Tags: android, sqlite, gradle, android-room, android-architecture-components

i have just changed the room library's version and gradle can not resolve it.

this is my repositories :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and build.gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
kapt  "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"
```

here's build log:

```
Failed to resolve: room-runtime-2.3.0
Failed to resolve: sqlite-framework-2.1.0
Failed to resolve: room-common-2.3.0
Failed to resolve: annotation-experimental-1.1.0
Failed to resolve: room-ktx-2.3.0
Failed to resolve: sqlite-2.1.0
```

How can I solve this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: lookout this,https://stackoverflow.com/a/63691426/12709358

Comment: changed the repositories and did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with room, it was because of Android Studio's cache. To solve the problem I deleted these 2 directories:

1. Build directory located in project's root directory
2. Build directory located in app directory